# encoding and escaping in PHP database backup scripts

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I tried lots of scripts to backup my mySQL database but they all fail..
phpMyAdmin is the only one that escapes my strings like it should.
What is wrong here?

In some strings in my database I have international characters like "é" etc.
The phpMyAdmin dump also shows me also things like "\r\n", that seem to break the scripts.

Is this an encoding problem? Should I not have "é" in my database in the first place?
All this encoding, escaping is way above my head, I am always struggling with this.
I just want everything human readable in my database and human readable parsed in the browser. Why is this so difficult?
I try to set everything to UTF-8, but when I send things up like with json_encode() I have all this \u00e9\ in the database.

I found a snipped that goes link this:

```
$tableName  = 'albums';
$backupFile = 'albums.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM '$tableName'";
$result     = mysql_query($query);
if (!$sql_res) { 
    echo "error";
}
```

the browser outputs "error"

Comment: which PHP module are you using? PDO, mysql, or mysqli?

Comment: eh, mysql. don't even know what the others are..

Comment: the SQL code has an error in it, it should be:  SELECT * FROM '$tableName' INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile'; and your check for an error looks at a non-existent variable, so it will always be false

Answer (score 0):

if you have command line access and have mysqldump installed (I believe most installations of mysql have it) then just run

```
mysqldump [database-name] -u[username] =p'[password]' > db_backup.sql
```

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: I want to write the backup with PHP, not with the command line

Comment: Then exec("mysqldump [database-name] -u[username] =p'[password]' > db_backup.sql");

Comment: I guess another way to to it would be to select everything in a table, dump all that into an array and then serialize it.  it's not pretty, may take up a ton of ram, but that *should* work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tableName  = 'albums';
$backupFile = 'albums.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} INTO OUTFILE '{$backupFile}'";
$result     = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) { 
    echo "error";
}
```

I suppose you're confident that your mysql connection was properly formed and that db was selected ok.